# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).stars is not a function

Tags: jquery

I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).stars is not a function

When running this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.rating_stars').html('<span class="stars">'+parseFloat(jQuery('input[name=amount]').val())+'</span>');
    jQuery('span.stars').stars();
});         



jQuery.fn.stars = function() {
    return jQuery(this).each(function() {
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat(jQuery(this).html())))) * 16));
    });
}
```

Comment: include this script in your page: https://github.com/viniciusmichelutti/jquery-stars/blob/master/src/stars.js